# How does an app know the path to open, when opening from address bar?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I open cmd/powershel/any other app from address bar in windows explorer, it automatically opens in the directory, that is currently opened. The question is: how does an app know this path? I thought, that it gets passed to an app as an argument, but then I wrote a simple program that just outputs all of its arguments and couldn't see any path. So, this is not argument based. Then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All processes have a special handle to their "[current directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/changing-the-current-directory)" aka "working directory", which they can change using [SetCurrentDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) or the POSIX chdir(). The working directory exists as a separate property alongside arguments or environment; it is automatically inherited from the parent process, but can also be explicitly specified during the [CreateProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) call.

Windows Explorer specifies `lpCurrentDirectory` when starting the program you're trying to launch from its address bar. On the other hand, when you use `cd` in CMD.exe, it uses SetCurrentDirectory() to switch its own working directory as well, and programs started from it directly inherit the working directory of the parent CMD.exe process. (Explorer used to do the same in Win98.)

The program you've opened can either explicitly call GetCurrentDirectory() or POSIX getcwd() to determine the location, or it can implicitly access it through relative paths such as `.`.

---

(Windows also has an additional hack to keep *per-drive* current directory, for compatibility with MS-DOS, but this is implemented through regular environment variables. This is described [in CreateProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) as well.)